# Is it possible to edit the name of a test run in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I was wondering if there is possible to edit the name of a test execution. So basically I run some test cases and know I have a test run with the title as shown in the image below. And I want to change its name to be something like "App. Base Tests 1.0". Does somebody know if it's possible?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It should be possible with the REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

Comment: @YanSklyarenko but without this it can't be done right? From the interface with like an edit button or something.

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean. No, I don't think it is possible. I think they treat the test runs as the "outcome" type of entity, which is not expected to be edited once created.